# How do I find the max index (z) of a value for each position (x) with in a data frame?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a series of data that are in a three column data frame (x, z, value) as such:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
z <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
value <- c(0,8,4,2,0,0,1,7,0,2,1,2,3,0,4)

df <- cbind(x, z, value)
df <- data.frame(df)
print(df)

> df
 x z value
 1 1     0
 1 2     8
 1 3     4
 1 4     2
 1 5     0
 2 1     0
 2 2     1
 2 3     7
 2 4     0
 2 5     2
 3 1     1
 3 2     2
 3 3     3
 3 4     0
 3 5     4
```

What I need to do is find the max value of z for each position x where the value is still a number (i.e. before it hits a final zero; there are zeros in the middle of the data for each value--I am interested in the last value). With in my data set, the full set is 50 by 25 (x,z). Ideal output would be like:

```
     x max.z
[1,] 1     4
[2,] 2     5
[3,] 3     5
```

Would be really interested in doing this without a for loop...either way, I appreciate the input!

Comment: Please edit the code so as the data matches the question. You make a vector named `z` but then you `cbind` something named `y`.

Comment: Done, sorry about that--had waffled on making it y or z and settled on z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dplyr solution:

```
df %>% group_by(x) %>% filter(value != 0) %>% summarize(max.z=max(z))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df2 = df[df$value != 0,]
t(sapply(split(df2, df2$x), function(a) a[NROW(a),1:2]))
#  x y
#1 1 4
#2 2 5
#3 3 5
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's an interesting way to do it. Thanks. I need to keep the zeros in the original and this subverts that. Awesome.